# Piping to a cmdlet with multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, piping

I have this cmdlet: (stripped down)

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Function Add-DatabaseUser()
{
    Param([string]$LogonName, [string]$UserName, [switch]$FullAccess)

    Write-Output($LogonName)
    Write-Output($UserName)
    Write-Output($FullAccess)
}
```

Is it possible to pipe something like an array of arrays to this cmdlet like this:

```
$users = @(
    @('user1', 'user1', $true),
    @('user2', 'user2', $false),
    @('user3', 'user4', $true),
    @('user4', 'user4', $true)
)

$users | Add-DatabaseUser
```

Rather than doing 4 individual calls to the cmdlet?

```
Add-DatabaseUser 'user1' 'user1' $true
Add-DatabaseUser 'user2' 'user2' $false
# etc.
```

**Update:**

I've followed Richards advice and created something to test the piped input, but something isn't right. Code below: (I've added `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true` to all parameters in the cmdlet)

```
$users = @(
 @{LogonName='user1'; UserName='user1'; FullAccess=$false},
 @{LogonName='user2'; UserName='user2'; FullAccess=$false}
)

$users | Add-DatabaseUser
```

This gives the following output:

```
System.Collections.HashTable
System.Collections.HashTable
True
System.Collections.HashTable
System.Collections.HashTable
False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You need to set the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` value for the parameter.

For example, from [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

```
Param
(
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
             ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
  [String[]]
  $ComputerName,
  …
)
```

With that definition, `$ComputerName` will be set from a property of that name on the object in the pipeline. (It will also match based on parameter name aliases.)

Comment: So would I have to use an array of hashes rather than an array of arrays in this case?

Comment: @Jake: Yes, you would need to do that. You could set up a parameter to accept an array, but that will be less clear for either the caller or the callee.

Comment: I'll give that a try. I'll update this in about 10 minutes.

Comment: see the edit to my OP. I think I've misunderstood you.

Comment: @Jake Rather than using hash tables try with `new-object PSObject -prop @{ hash table goes here }`: you might need real object properties.